# android- pass credential for sip registration

Tags: android, port, registration, sip

I want to know if there is anyway to pass credentials during sipRegistration.What I have done is read the client's registration request, and using a UDP server reply to the client's Ip and port a success message. In this way the registration is successful and calls can be made directly without using sipServer. But the problem is I want to fix the port at which the sip Client is listening for success message.

Is there any way I can set this listening port or send this credential in the registration request packet.

Comment: You need to provide some details -- are you using the build-in SIP stack or a third party one? Generally you cannot fix listen ports, etc. if it is not in the API.

Comment: I'm using android sip api. Details like? I used wireshark to sniff the packets sent during registration request by sip client. Used some of the credentials from the request packed to send response back to the client, one of the credential is Port number.

Comment: to make my question simpler: I want to know if there is any way I can specify the port at which client will be listening for "registration success response from the server"

Comment: No, not with the default client at least. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: Okay, wanted to avoid server and also seems like android sip api doesn allow voice calls without client being registered.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot fix ports with the default SIP client. It provides a fairly high-level interface and if you want to tweak options or extend it might not be a very good fit. Also it hasn't changes since 2.3, so not too clear whether it will evolve at all.

Comment: Any suggestions... some tutorial links will be helpful

Comment: Just select on of the popular SIP libraries, they have tutorial, etc.